# How to color parts of an Image Mask with the original target Image color using opencv or PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I need help to create a mask of an image where parts of the image are black due to Masking but some part still retain the original color of the image. Imagine a thug that wears a ski mask where part of the eye and mouth is the thug's skin while the rest of the face are covered with the ski mask.
[image: example]

Basically what I want is the eyebrows, eye and lips part should retain the original image but the rest of the mask stay white like the picture above.
So far by using PIL, I have successfully create a mask and fill out the inside of the "eye" part with black color

```
def getmask(img,jawline,eyebrows,eyes,mouth):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    imArray = np.asarray(img)
    # create mask
    polygon = jawline.flatten().tolist()
    maskIm = Image.new('L', (imArray.shape[1], imArray.shape[0]), 0)
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=1, fill='white')
    #ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(polygon, outline=(1))
    # draw eyes
    righteyes=eyes[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(righteyes, outline=1,fill='black')
    lefteyes=eyes[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(lefteyes, outline=1,fill='black')
    mask = np.array(maskIm)
    # draw eyebrows
    rightbrows=eyebrows[0:6].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(rightbrows, outline=2, fill='black')
    leftbrows=eyebrows[6:].flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(leftbrows, outline=2, fill='black')
    # draw mouth
    mouth=mouth.flatten().tolist()
    ImageDraw.Draw(maskIm).polygon(mouth, outline=1, fill='black')

    mask = np.array(maskIm)
    return mask
```

those jawline, eyebrows, eyes, mouth contains the (x,y) coordinate for the related part of the face and I only need to retain the color on Eyebrows,eyes and mouth part. I hope someone can help me solve it

Comment: How do you imagine anyone can help without seeing either the starting image or the result you expect? Please provide both, thanks.

Comment: I have added the original image and output that I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a mask where by the area's you want to keep are in white then you can simply do a `bitwise_or` with it on the original image.

In your case we have to invert the mask so that the background is black and the ROI's are white.

```
mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
masked = cv2.bitwise_or(image, image, mask=mask)
```

Here is an example of the output:
[image: masked image]
For the rest of his face to be black you would just set all the values outside of the ROI to black in the mask. One way would be to use the coordinates provided by
`np.where(mask != 0)`

Example Code:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vCMhgDXmuFMJpxChuLN6TDEqgXi7V8CT